# Query : Error in clock divider used in VGA Controller (Verilog) Basys 2 board

Tags: verilog, vga

I am getting an error while incorporating clock divider ( 40 MHz ) in my VGA Controller (Basys 2 board ). Error in my coding is - Port I of input buffer instance_name/CLKIN_IBUFG_INST is connected to GND.
Please help in removing this error !

Code is as follows :

```
module anymodule(input wire clk,reset,
output wire hsynch,vsynch,
output [2:0] red,
output [2:0] green,
output [1:0] blue,
output video_on);


// defining constants
localparam HD = 800; // horizontal display area
localparam HF = 40; // front porch (right border)
localparam HB = 88; //right porch (left border)
localparam HR = 128; // horizontal retrace
localparam VD = 600; // vertical display area
localparam VF = 1; // front porch (bottom border)
localparam VB = 23; // back porch (top border)
localparam VR = 4; // vertical retrace

wire pixel_tick;


//clock divider

// Instantiate the module
clkdiv instance_name (
    .CLKIN_IN(CLKIN_IN), 
    .RST_IN(RST_IN), 
    .CLKFX_OUT(pixel_tick), 
    .CLKIN_IBUFG_OUT(CLKIN_IBUFG_OUT), 
    .CLK0_OUT(CLK0_OUT), 
    .LOCKED_OUT(LOCKED_OUT)
    );




//horizontal and vertical counter

reg [9:0] h_count = 0;
reg [9:0] v_count = 0;
wire [9:0] h_end,v_end;

assign h_end = HD+HF+HR+HB-1;
assign v_end = VD+VF+VR+VB-1;


always @(pixel_tick)
if(h_count<h_end)
h_count <= h_count+1;
else
h_count <= 0;


always @(*)
if(pixel_tick & h_end)
if(v_count<v_end)
v_count <= v_count+1;
else
v_count <= 0;
else
v_count <= v_count;


assign hsynch = ((h_count>= HD+HF-1) && (h_count<=HD+HF+HR+HB-1));
assign vsynch = ((v_count>=VD+VF-1) && (v_count<= VD+VF+VR+VB-1));
assign video_on = ((h_count <HD) && (v_count<VD));

wire [9:0] pixel_x,pixel_y;
assign pixel_x = (video_on)? h_count : 'b0;
assign pixel_y = (video_on)? v_count : 'b0;


reg [7:0] coloroutput;


always @(pixel_tick)
if(~video_on)
coloroutput <= 0;
else
begin
if(pixel_y<160)
coloroutput[7:5] <= 3'b111;
else if(pixel_y<320)
coloroutput[4:2] <= 3'b111;
else
coloroutput[1:0] <= 2'b11;
end


assign red = (video_on)?coloroutput[7:5] : 3'b000;
assign green = (video_on)?coloroutput[4:2] : 3'b000;
assign blue = (video_on)?coloroutput[1:0] : 3'b000;


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching your code for `CLKIN_IN` it only appears on the following line, which means there is nothing driving it ie connected to ground (GND).

```
// Instantiate the module
clkdiv instance_name (
    .CLKIN_IN(CLKIN_IN),  //<-- Not connected
```

If variables are not declared logic/wire/reg/tri etc then a 1 bit wire is implied so you do not get the type checking of an unconnected port, it is however un-driven. Simulation should show this as a Z driving in.

Comment: Hi, I changed the input clock signal name from CLKIN_IN to my clock i.e clk. the module now is succeessfully synthesized but when I go for generating .bit file I now get an error which says - "Place:1012 - A clock IOB / DCM component pair have been found that are not placed at an optimal clock IOB / DCM
   site pair.

Comment: If this answer answered your question it would be helpful if you accepted it so others know it is solved. Please ask another new question for the follow up so each question can get the best answers. Thanks